# Which is the best tool for automation a third party window application?

Tags: ui-automation

I am new to automation for Windows apps, apart from using basic Sikuli.

I checked some options like PyAutoGUI, PyWinAuto. Which is the best tool for automation of a 3rd party Windows application out of Sikuli, PyAutoGUI, PyWinAuto or any other tool?

Preferable - a  cross platform tool (Mac and Windows)

Comment: "Which is the best tool to do ..." type of questions do not belong here as they are opinion-based.

Answer (score 7):

If you need text properties based automation, pywinauto should help you. But there is no popular text-based cross-platform tool in Open Source field.

On macOs [pyatom/ATOMac](https://github.com/pyatom/pyatom) is good enough if you prefer Python (it requires some compilation during setup, but works well).

This is [the big list of open source tools](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/wiki/UI-Automation-tools-ratings) I'm maintaining.

- PyAutoGUI has image recognition capabilities (like Sikuli or Lackey) but it's not text based (even no Win32 API support).
- PyAutoIt bindings and AutoIt itself doesn't support MS UI Automation technology (only Win32 API).
- The [Getting Started Guide for pywinauto](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) explains some differences between these 2 technologies and how to switch between them in pywinauto.

Anyway this field is complicated and you may face many challenges. Feel free to ask more detailed questions because this question is more suitable for 

[Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange site.

Comment: Thanks Vasily, it helps! :)